# Different buckets in influx from telegraf

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I've tried to set up a second bucket, but everyting that goes into the existing bucket is being put into the new bucket. Why?

```
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]
  token = "token=="
  organization = "mini31"
  bucket = "zigbee"

 [[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]
  topics = [
    "zigbee2mqtt/Home/+/Temp",
  ]
  data_format = "json_v2"
  [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2]]
    measurement_name = "temperature"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.topic_parsing]]
      topic = "zigbee2mqtt/Home/+/Temp"
      tags = "_/_/room/_"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.field]]
      path = "temperature"
      type = "float"

# this is supposed to be the new bucket, but it's receiving everytyhing from zigbee.
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]
  token = "token=="
  organization = "mini31"
  bucket = "solar"

  [[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
    servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]
    topics = [
      "solar/inverter"
    ]
    data_format = "json_v2"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2]]
      measurement_name = "generation"
      [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.field]]
        path = "ppv"
        rename = "generation"
        type = "int"
```

How can I keep the existing zigbee stuff going into its bucket but stop it from also going into the new bucket?

*Attempt 2*

```
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]
  token = "token=="
  organization = "mini31"
  bucket = ""
  bucket_tag = "bucket"

  [[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
   servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]
   topics = [
     "zigbee2mqtt/Home/+/Temp",
   ]
   data_format = "json_v2"
   exclude_bucket_tag = true
   [inputs.mqtt_consumer.tags]
     bucket = "zigbee"
   [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2]]
     measurement_name = "temperature"
     [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.topic_parsing]]
       topic = "zigbee2mqtt/Home/+/Temp"
       tags = "_/_/room/_"
     [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.field]]
       path = "temperature"
       type = "float"

  [[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
    servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]
    topics = [
      "solar/inverter"
    ]
    data_format = "json_v2"
    exclude_bucket_tag = true
    [inputs.mqtt_consumer.tags]
      bucket = "solar"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2]]
      measurement_name = "generation"
      [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.field]]
        path = "ppv"
        rename = "generation"
        type = "int"
```

And now telegraf fails to start with the meaningless message:

> `E! [telegraf] Error running agent: error loading config file /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf: plugin inputs.mqtt_consumer: line 1415: configuration specified the fields ["exclude_bucket_tag"], but they weren't used`
> Which still happens if I comment out `exclude_bucket_tag`.

Comment: exclude_bucket_tag cannot be part of inputs.mqtt_consumer. You have that twice in your config, so commenting one out will still give error for the second..

Answer (score 0):

With this configuration Telegraf does not know that it should avoid writing certain inputs to the available outputs, i.e., by default, all inputs are written to all outputs.

There are several ways to split `measurements` across `buckets`, one of the ways is to state that the `output` only considers a certain kind of measurements. As an example, the output with the `bucket="zigbee"` should have a property `namepass = ["temperature"]` (given that the zigbee sensors are writing temperature measurements). The same logic applies to the `solar`bucket, and you can only allow `generation` namepass. You can find out more about this on [InfluxDB docs](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md).

This is all using your first configuration, the second one seems to have only one output thus it will not work.